# Spring MVC project migrated from Eclipse to Intelli J

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I have one spring MVC project in eclipse neon and it is working fine. But because of some reason I want to import that project into intelli J idea 2017. I created a new project in intelli J using the **File -> New -> Project from Existing Sources** and I got all my files but I can't understand how to run this in intelli J.

I can't find an option to add a Tomcat server or Add a run configuration.

Can someone help me with this?

I am attaching a screenshot of my project structure for reference[![project structure
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myUkh.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myUkh.jpg)

**EDIT** I have ULTIMATE edition of intelli J

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-running-your-first-web-application.html

Comment: @CrazyCoder The instructions are for web applications, will the same step be valid for Spring application also?

Comment: Yes, you are deploying to Tomcat, so the steps are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Under the "run" menu you should (if you have the Ultimate rather than the Community edition of intelliJ) be able to create all the run configurations you want for Tomcat or pretty much any other application server known to Duke.
In the free version, your options there will be pretty limited.

Comment: When I am trying to create a Tomcat server it is giving me an error saying "No artifact found", The artifact tag is empty

Comment: did you set the artfacts to deploy in the deployment tab? And the build actions to be performed before launch?